# Weird width in UITableView on iOS 11

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios11, xcode9

I just added an `UITableView` with top `UISearchBar` into my view but only on iOS 11, the table view has more width than my search bar, this is my code:

```
    self.autocompleteTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: self.storeSearchBar.frame.origin.x, y: self.storeSearchBar.frame.origin.y + self.storeSearchBar.frame.size.height, width: self.storeSearchBar.bounds.width, height: 200.0))
    self.autocompleteTableView!.alpha = 0.8
    self.autocompleteTableView!.delegate = self
    self.autocompleteTableView!.dataSource = self
    self.autocompleteTableView!.separatorStyle = .none
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.autocompleteTableView!.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea = true
    }

    self.storeSearchBar.alpha = 0.8
    self.storeSearchBar.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.autocompleteTableView!)
    self.autocompleteTableView!.isHidden = true

    let searchBar = self.storeSearchBar!
    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In which method are you setting the frame?

Comment: I'm setting the frame on viewDidload with this config @MaulikBhuptani

Comment: Try setting only frame of UITableView & UISearchBar in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: ok, that was the problem. Thanks @MaulikBhuptani

Comment: You are welcome buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, thanks to @MaulikBhuptani, the answer is:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.autocompleteTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 
    self.storeSearchBar.frame.origin.x, y: self.storeSearchBar.frame.origin.y + self.storeSearchBar.frame.size.height, width: self.storeSearchBar.bounds.width, height: 200.0))
    self.autocompleteTableView!.alpha = 0.8
    self.autocompleteTableView!.delegate = self
    self.autocompleteTableView!.dataSource = self
    self.autocompleteTableView!.separatorStyle = .none
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.autocompleteTableView!.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea = true
    }

    self.storeSearchBar.alpha = 0.8
    self.storeSearchBar.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.autocompleteTableView!)
    self.autocompleteTableView!.isHidden = true

    let searchBar = self.storeSearchBar!
    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
}
```